# Configure Keycloak TLS to use Trusted Platform Module (TPM) private key

Tags: ssl, keycloak, tpm

I'm trying to configure Keycloak TLS using a self signed certificate, the private key of which is stored in TPM (Trusted Platform Module). So I have the certificate PEM file, but I don't have the private key in a PEM file as it is not exportable. Is there a way to configure Keycloak TLS to use TPM as a key store?